# How to revert some of the changes made by a newer commit?

Tags: git

I want to undo some, but not all, of the changes that I made in one file with the latest commit.
Preferably the partly reverted file should then reside in my working directory.

I get confused by `checkout --patch filename`, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to make a new commit on-top or replace the existing commit?

Comment: Committing on top works fine. The important thing regarding this question is the magic `--patch` option that I never used before, explained below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said yourself, `git checkout --patch` is the best way to go about doing this. You might be confused because you need to specify the tree-ish object (commit or branch) to check out from. In your particular example, you would want `git checkout --patch HEAD~1`

`git checkout --patch` behaves very similarly to `git add --patch`, except it adds from another tree to the working directory instead of the working directory to the index.

What happens once you type out which tree and paths you want to check out is git displays a chunk-by-chunk diff between your file and the one you want to check out. Then, you can specify whether you want to apply the chunk, reject the chunk, or split the chunk into smaller pieces. Press `?` in this interactive tool to get a full list of what you can do.

It should look something like this:

```
$ # git checkout --patch <tree>  <path>
$   git checkout --patch 9e881cb conf/nginx.conf 
diff --git b/conf/nginx.conf a/conf/nginx.conf
index ff0454a..a3c3ed7 100644
--- b/conf/nginx.conf
+++ a/conf/nginx.conf
@@ -1,12 +1,8 @@
 server {
   server_name strikeskids.com;
+  root /www/strikeskids;

   location / {
-    root /www/strikeskids/jekyll;
     try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html =404;
   }
-
-  location /up/ {
-    root /www/strikeskids;
-  }
 }
Apply this hunk to index and worktree [y,n,q,a,d,/,s,e,?]? s <=== split 
                             chunk into smaller pieces
Split into 3 hunks.
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 server {
   server_name strikeskids.com;
+  root /www/strikeskids;

   location / {
Apply this hunk to index and worktree [y,n,q,a,d,/,j,J,g,e,?]? y <=== include
                             this chunk in the checkout
@@ -3,5 +4,4 @@

   location / {
-    root /www/strikeskids/jekyll;
     try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html =404;
   }
Apply this hunk to index and worktree [y,n,q,a,d,/,K,j,J,g,e,?]? n <=== do not
                             include this chunk in the checkout
@@ -6,7 +6,3 @@
     try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html =404;
   }
-
-  location /up/ {
-    root /www/strikeskids;
-  }
 }
Apply this hunk to index and worktree [y,n,q,a,d,/,K,g,e,?]? q <== finish now, 
                             including the chunks I've specified but not any others
```

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout HEAD~1 path/to/file` gives you previous version of the file. Then you could undo the changes you want to keep (so, make a file to look like you want it) and then commit changes as usual.

Comment: and that's the alternative if you are **not** allowed to rewrite history :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to **rewrite** your history (if your commit wasn't pushed to a remote repository yet for example):

```
# undo your commit
git reset HEAD~
# now remove the changes you didn't want in your last commit
# and commit again
git commit
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can *always* overwrite your history, but the server may not allow non-fast-forward pushes, and even if it does it may not be a good idea.

Comment: I know, but I didn't want to go too much in depth on this issue, but a little warning is always necessary. Suppose the commit is only local; then he can rewrite history. If it is a commit only on a development branch, then I would allow rewriting history if he is the only developer working on that branch...

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to achieve this:

1) Since you have already committed the code, use

git reset --soft HEAD^

This would uncommit the code and now you can modify the file as per your requirement.

2) With version control systems like Git, you should not worry of commits as it basically has all your history.
You can go ahead and do the changes on top of this commit to basically remove the code which you have mistakenly committed.

But prefer option 2 only if you have to modify small amount of code, otherwise go for option 1.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you will be interested by the very good post on the github blog on [How to undo (almost) anything with Git](https://github.com/blog/2019-how-to-undo-almost-anything-with-git)...